# Weighted sum of an input inside the network

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

I have a network with multiple inputs and I split out the first 10 inputs and calculate the weighted sum, and then concatenate it with the rest of the input:

```
first = Lambda(lambda z: z[:, 0:11])(d_inputs)
wsum_first = Lambda(calcWSumF)(first )
d_input = concatenate([d_inputs, wsum_first], axis=-1)
```

with the function defined as:

```
w_vec = K.constant(np.array([range(10)]*64).reshape(10, 64)) # batch size is 64
def calcWSumF(x):
    y = K.dot(w_vec, x)
    y = K.expand_dims(y, -1)       
    return y
```

I want a constant vector to be used to calculate the weighted sum of the first part of the input. The concatenation doesn't work because the shapes don't match. How can I implement this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this much better using `K.sum` and only a vector containing the coefficients. Further, there is no need to use a fixed batch size (it can be any number):

```
def calcWSumF(x, idx):
    w_vec = K.constant(np.arange(idx))
    y = K.sum(x[:, 0:idx] * w_vec, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    return y

d_inputs = Input((15,))
wsum_first = Lambda(calcWSumF, arguments={'idx': 10})(d_inputs)
d_input = concatenate([d_inputs, wsum_first], axis=-1)

model = Model(d_inputs, d_input)
model.predict(np.arange(15).reshape(1, 15))

# output:
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,
         11.,  12.,  13.,  14., 285.]], dtype=float32)

# Note: 0*0 + 1*1 + 2*2 + ... + 9*9 = 285
```

Note that, to make it more general, we have added another argument (`idx`) to the lambda function which specifies how many of the elements from the beginning we would like to consider.

Comment: Very nice solution